# oracle adf or oracle forms

Tags: oracleforms, oracle-adf

What are the advantages of oracle forms over adf, and also disadvantages.
Does some companies replaces oracle forms with adf and why?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, Oracle has ceased the Forms as a project some time ago, now it also stopped supporting it.
Forms used to be a framework for desktop applications with easy connection to Oracle database, pretty much like VBS on top of Access.
ADF is a complete framework covering all middleware aspects of an MVC architecture.
Comparing ADF to Forms is something like comparing Ferrari to Yugo.

Comment: Nice answer, but will web replace desktop ? In desktop app it is very fast to insert new records, just using the keyboard. But in browser i doubt that some employee can have bigger speed of entering data than desktop.

Comment: Oh no, ofc not, both desktop and web apps stay! You see, ADF is just a more organized replacement for the Forms. It's built on top of MVC architecture in order to split up different aspects of an implementation. One builds the model - just once - it's the mirror of your database, then you can have a Swing or a Web application with this same model. In this document https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jdev/collateral/papers/10g/ADF_overview.pdf&pli=1 check the image on page 7, the blue parts are ADF.

Answer (score 1):

advantages of oracle forms over adf is oracle forms are much fast as compare to adf form and easy connection to Oracle database not need to lot java code to get stored procedure/dyanmic query just connect and start writing pl/sql.